# What are best practices to organise large amount of binary files?

Tags: database, performance, sqlite, filesystems, blob

I'm trying to develop standalone (desktop) app.
The goal I'm trying to achieve is to create efficient storage for large binary data. As long as I don't want to save it in database, which I would better utilize for storing metadata, what are the choices to save binary objects in filesystem?

I can imagine file directory with a set of files named with the hash of their content, for example, md5. The obvious advantage is that I have all the 'light' metadata and hashes in database, decreasing the load on it and also could easily load binary file knowing the hash when needed.

But I feel this solution could have caveats I don't see right now, because a lot of programs use some non-obvious dir structure, similar to Firefox's cache or storage of git. Why do there incorporate complex directories tree? How this type of storage is named and what are it's pros/cons?

Edit: I've reasoning not to store blobs in db, because I use sqlite and it gets significally slower with data amount constantly increasing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some filesystems don't handle well directories with too many files in them. Because of that, a workaround was introduced and became common.

Instead of storing all files in the same directory, you use, say, 3-levels of directory nesting. Root directory (root of your file storage, not system root, of course) contains only other directories, each containing other directories, each containing other directories. And you store files in those leaf directories.

If on the first level you have 100 directories, then on the second you have 10k (100 * 100) and on the third - 1kk (100 * 100 * 100).

For example, you have a filename "a05c04c9c71c2dbd7f11ca175a1d289c70d684ac.dat". First six chars of the filename define folder names. So you should store it to

```
/a0/5c/04/a05c04c9c71c2dbd7f11ca175a1d289c70d684ac.dat
```

Alternatively, you can generate directory names randomly:

```
/rand(100)/rand(100)/rand(100)/a05c04c9c71c2dbd7f11ca175a1d289c70d684ac.dat
```

Comment: Nice explanation, thanks. Just a little clarification on numbers: given 2 alphanumeric characters in a directory name, each directory would contain up to 35*35=1225 dirs. Or, generally speaking, 35 in a power of numer of symbols in dirname.

Comment: Yes, something like that. You should test that, maybe even this number is too much. I've posted another approach.